# Count lines in a file using bash and add the result in the first line

Tags: bash, line, wc

I have a text file:

```
10 20 30 40
50 60 60 80
```

By using

```
$ wc -l file.txt
2 file.txt
```

I get the count, but I want to add that result in my text file.

I want the result to be like this:

```
2
10 20 30 40
50 60 70 80
```

What should I do in order to prepend the result in the text file?

I have many of these files in one folder, and instead of providing a single text file at a time, I want to provide all the files at the same time.

Comment: Try here: http://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash

Comment: start here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

For one file, you can do this:

```
wc -l < file.txt | cat - file.txt > tmp && mv tmp file.txt
```

This uses `cat` to concatenate the result of `wc -l < file.txt` with the contents of `file.txt`. The result is written to a temporary file, then the original file is overwritten.

For many files (e.g. all files ending in `.txt`), you can use a loop:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    wc -l < "$file" | cat - "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"
done
```

Comment: @BHAV247 without commenting thanks, if it's working then accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo `wc -l myfile.txt` | cat - myfile.txt > tmp && mv tmp myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk may be your friend :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$"}NR=FNR{printf "%d\n%s",gsub(/\n/,"\n"),$0}' file \
> temp && mv temp file
```